# Rails 4 Rspec expect{}.to change not registering despite test working as planned

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, rspec, rspec2

I am working with Rails 4, RSpec, Capybara, and selenium. I have come across an oddity that I cant seem to puzzle out, having tried for the last day or so. I have a fairly basic request spec failing because the test is not registering a change to the model.  Here is my spec:

```
describe "manage pages", :js => true do
    before :each do
        @fake_page = FactoryGirl.create(:page_with_block, name: "Foobar")
        @fake_page2 = FactoryGirl.create(:page_with_block, name: "sdfdf")
        visit admin_pages_path
        save_page
    end

    it "should delete an image when link is clicked" do
        expect {
            within "#page_#{@fake_page.id}" do
                click_link 'Destroy'
            end
            wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new ignore: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError
            alert = wait.until { page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert }
            alert.accept
        }.to change(Page, :count).by(-1)
        expect(page).to have_content "Listing Pages"
        expect(page).not_to have_content "Foobar"   
        save_page           
    end
end
```

As you can see it is a basic click on destroy and confirm the js alert test. The problem is that it always fails:

```
......F

Failures:

  1) Pages manage pages should delete an image when link is clicked
     Failure/Error: expect {
       expected #count to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/requests/admin/pages_spec.rb:116:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 11.74 seconds (files took 3.81 seconds to load)
7 examples, 1 failure
```

According to the save_page files I've placed in my before, and the one at the end of the test when I comment out the 'expect.to change', everything is working as intended, the fake pages are created in the before, the test goes through and clicks destroy and accepts the alert, the page is destroyed and the index page is reloaded without it on the content. What i dont understand is why the Change matcher does not see that it is, in fact, working.

I have read that it may have to do with my rails_helper.rb file but everything I looked up has a similar, if not exact, setup:

```
    ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include Capybara::DSL

    config.before(:suite) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
        DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    end
    config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    end
    config.before(:each, :js => true) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end
    config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.start
    end 
    config.after(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end 

    config.after(:suite) do
        FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/test/system/"])
    end


end
```

Since I can find no other occurrence of this on google or this site, I must simply be doing something wrong here. Can anyone point me to the flaw in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This exact same thing happens to me constantly. For the most part, I've resorted (where possible) to checking via the UI of the app itself to see if whatever appropriate record(s) has been created or destroyed, and then get rid of that statement. But there are some places where what's created/destroyed isn't practically accessible from the UI via a test. Did you figure this out by any chance? If so, I'd love to know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same issue. You wait logic might have flaws. I used [this approach](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara) and it worked well for me.

Copypasted from this article - basically you need to create a helper:

```
# spec/support/wait_for_ajax.rb
module WaitForAjax
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
      loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
  end

  def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include WaitForAjax, type: :feature
end
```

Include all support files automatically in your `spec_helper.rb`

```
spec/support/**/*.rb in our spec_helper.rb
```

or do it manually, like me:

```
#rails_helper.rb
require_relative 'support/wait_for_ajax'
```

Now my test passes!

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Call Me Back contact front feature spec >", :type => :feature, js: true do
feature 'valid form' do
  scenario "with name and phone" do
    visit '/'
    execute_script '$("#call-popup").fadeIn(300)'

    fill_in 'call_me_back_request_name', with: 'Clark Kent'
    fill_in 'call_me_back_request_phone', with: '1234445566'

    within '#new_call_me_back_request' do
      expect{
        find("input[type='submit']").click
        wait_for_ajax #<- the magic is here!
      }.to change(Request, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```